# How to change the status bar icon color in kitkat and lollipop?

Tags: android, icons, statusbar

I want to change the color of status bar icons in my app. I googled it a lot but i did not found any thing. Plz provide me any help. For API below 23.

Thanks

Comment: Please be clear on the question. Is it the status bar color you're trying to change? or status bar icon? you mean notification icon?

Comment: ya i want to change status bar icon color

Answer (score 3):

This is possible on API level 23 and higher

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Comment: As you said API>23, then its off-topic and should not answer. Use comment instead.