# How to change color of StatusBar icons on Lollipop?

Tags: android, styles, statusbar

I need to **invert the colors of the icons** when the StatusBar is set to some light color like white.

I've come across with following attribute for API 23 and higher

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

But I need workaround for Lollipop API 21 and 22 versions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Image from an [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33894882/6272369)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color

Comment: @Kuffs Thank you for the reference. I've already read that question and best answer says that recommended color for Notifications in Lollipop is white. But no clear answer with the code is provided as a workaround

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201338/how-to-change-the-status-bar-icon-color-in-kitkat-and-lollipop

Comment: @Kuffs I've read this one too. Accepted answer is about the StatusBar color. Not the icons of it.